# Remove field from an embedded document

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to execute a pretty straight forward script to remove all of my empty values from my document. The document has this structure:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a75caa4ce7a49e7d8474a40"), 
"icao" : "MLA", 
"name" : "40-Mile Air", 
"callsign" : "MILE-AIR", 
"country" : "US", 
"alid" : 10, 
"mode" : "F", 
"active" : "Y", 
"routes" : [ { "codeshare" : "", 
    "dst_ap" : "TKJ", 
    "dst_apid" : 7235, 
    "equipment" : "CNA", 
    "rid" : 46585 } ]
```

The script I am executing is this:

```
db.airlines.updateMany(
{ codeshare: "" },
{ $unset: {codeshare : 1}},
)
```

However after running I am getting this error:

```
2018-02-07T10:17:35.634+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):3:21
```

Comment: Are you aware `codeshare` is a field in an embedded document and is not at root level as suggested by your current query?

Comment: Yes, I tried with routes.codeshare but still no results.

Comment: `routes.$.codeshare`

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I think the problem is with the condition `{routes.codeshare:""}` because it only runs the script whenever this condition does not exists. But even though running the script, it still doesn't delete the field _codeshare_

Comment: The query that you posted does not produce that error message but another one caused by the trailing comma `,`.

Comment: After modifying to this:  `db.airlines.updateMany(
{ routes.$.codeshare:""},
{ $unset: {routes.$.codeshare : 1}}
);` 

I am getting the same error on a different place. 

`2018-02-07T10:52:11.983+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):2:8
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the [**`$unset`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) operator together with the [**`$`** positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) in your update to remove the embedded `codeshare` field.

The [**`$`** positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) will identify the correct element in the array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array, thus your final update statement should look like:

```
db.airlines.updateMany(
    { "routes.codeshare": "" }, 
    { "$unset": { "routes.$.codeshare": 1 } }
)
```

---

For multiple elements within an array, use the filtered positional operator **[`$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)** which identifies the array elements that match the arrayFilters conditions:

```
db.airlines.updateMany(
   { "routes.codeshare": "" }, 
   { "$unset": { "routes.$[element].codeshare" : 1 } },
   { "arrayFilters": [ { "element.codeshare": "" } ] }
)
```

Comment: It worked ! Thank you a lot . I thought you need **$** on both statements to identify that it is an embedded document.

Comment: It's only required in the update operator, not the query

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

db.airlines.update({ name: "40-Mile Air" },{ $unset: {codeshare : "" }})

Comment: It matches it but it does not modify it

`WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })`

On top of that I have around 5000 records so I need to run updateMany for all of them.

Comment: { $unset:{routes[0].codeshare: '' ''} } check this once